# Accessing Variable Values on External PHP code

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to PHP and Laravel, I'm trying to do the following:

1-I have an API that receives a Post and stores data in a table. 2-When the Controller that executes the above instruction is activated, I would like to execute an external php code. I'm having trouble reading the values ​​of the variables that should be sent to the external php and accessed, how can I do that? 3-I've tried to use the Session concept but without success, to try to get the values ​​of the variables in the session.

4- Below is the part of the code that makes the external php call, for which I want to get the values ​​of the various "number" and "audio".

```
public function store(Request $request){

Session::put('number', $request->input('number'));

exec("php -f /var/www/html/fpbxcalls/app/Freeswitch/send_call.php >> /tmp/send_call.log &");

$fpbxcalls = new v_calls;
$fpbxcalls->audio = $request->input('audio');
$fpbxcalls->number = $request->input('number');
$fpbxcalls->content = $request->input('content');

if( $fpbxcalls->save() ){
  return new fpbxcallsresource( $fpbxcalls );
}
}
```

Comment: You're mixing at least 2 concepts here, sessions and remote calls. What exactly are you trying to do and what does "external php code" mean? Where does it reside in relation to the Laravel application?

Comment: Thanks for ansewring. Sorry, i meam external code, but the right concept is that the code is in the same enviromenent, but only a new code, it is inside the same Laravel aplication folder, it is located on /var/www/html/fpbxcalls/app/Freeswitch/send_call.php